# AWS Cognito Identity JS: Forget/Remember/Do Not Remember Device

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm working with the AWS Cognito Identity JS SDK (https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js) and I'm trying to set up a few buttons to test the `setDeviceStatusRemembered`, `setDeviceStatusNotRemembered`, and `forgetDevice` functionality but I keep getting an error saying:

`MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'DeviceKey' in params`

Here is an implementation of one of the functions:

```
forgetDevice = function(){

var cognitoUser = userPool.getCurrentUser();

if (cognitoUser != null) {
    cognitoUser.getSession(function(err, session) {
        if (err) {
            alert(err);
            signOut();
            return;
        }

        console.log('session validity: ' + session.isValid());

        cognitoUser.forgetDevice({
            onSuccess: function (result) {
                console.log('call result: ' + result);
            },
            onFailure: function(err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    });
  } 
}
```

If I  change up the function like this:

```
forgetDevice = function(cognitoUser){
    cognitoUser.forgetDevice({
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('call result: ' + result);
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
}
```

and I call the function from the `cognitoUser.authenticateUser` `success` callback function, passing `cognitoUser` as argument into the `forgetDevice` function above everything works perfectly.

From looking at the `session` object in the first implementation it appears that the `session` object does not contain the `DeviceKey` property so the `cognitoUser.forgetDevice()` call fails.

What I'm trying to figure out is, should I just be calling the  `setDeviceStatusRemembered`, `setDeviceStatusNotRemembered`, and `forgetDevice` functions on login, or should I be able to call them any time within my application? Hopefully that makes sense. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help:

Note that if device tracking is enabled for the user pool with a setting that user opt-in is required, you need to implement an onSuccess(result, userConfirmationNecessary) callback, collect user input and call either setDeviceStatusRemembered to remember the device or setDeviceStatusNotRemembered to not remember the device.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-device-tracking.html

Also can you attempt calling getCachedDeviceKeyAndPassword to populate the deviceKey in the CognitoUser object?

Comment: You are awesome! calling getCachedDeviceKeyAndPassword worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: I am also facing similar issue. I sign up to create new account, enable MFA from client. I logout. I login again with newly created account. I am challenged with chose MFA type to fill the authentication code (from either google authenticator app or sms). I also select "remember me" option and login. But, when i login again, it asks for authentication code again and only after 2nd login aws cognito "Remembered" field is getting updated to remember. I am using setDeviceStatusRemembered() after login to remember device. Could you help resolve this issue?

Comment: @ananyaaathrey Were you able to fix this issue? I am also facing the same. Have added the details as last comment in this ticket: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8977