# AWS Cognito Missing required key 'DeviceKey' in params

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Hi doing my user management using the so useful Amazon web service Cognito.

I would remember my users devices on login but when I'm calling the

> cognitoUser.setDeviceStatusRemembered()

I have this error message :

> Missing required key 'DeviceKey' in params

This is how I have implement it:

```
  AuthService.login($scope.username.toLowerCase(), $scope.password)
           .then(function(res) {
              if ($scope.rememberMe == true)
                AuthService.setRememberedDevice($scope.username);
            })
```

My login function is well working for a long time.

I have read on this question : 
[AWS Cognito Identity JS: Forget/Remember/Do Not Remember Device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44792164/aws-cognito-identity-js-forget-remember-do-not-remember-device])

...that a call to the getCachedDeviceKeyAndPassword() could solve this problem but I can not figure out where to find an implementation of this method or how to use it.

I think @Ionut Trestian could know the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Which enviornment are you running? If you run it in a browser, the tokens and device keys are stored in local storage, and if you run it in a server side enviornment, they are stored in memory.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Summer Guo , I'm doing both. I run in in my firefox browser in dev and in an Apache server in production and in both cases I have the same error message 'Missing required key 'DeviceKey' in params'. Do you know how to fixe it ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which SDK/library you are using. With the current Amplify library, you can get the device key through the user object:

```
Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
}).then(user => {
  user.getCachedDeviceKeyAndPassword(); // without this line, the deviceKey is null
  console.log(user.deviceKey);
});
```